# How to have comments appearing in file only locally but not remotely (when pushing)?

Tags: git

```
//I would like this comment to appear only locally. When I push to a remotely tracked branch, 
//this comment shouldn't appear for other developers to see.

function test(){
  console.log('whatever');
}

test();
```

I'm not referring to `.gitignore` as I'm trying to ignore partially parts of the file.

Comment: How would you envision this working when pulling new changes from a repository?

Comment: Thanks for indicating that. I was sure that question would have been asked but spent a good 10 minutes and couldn't find those answers.

Comment: @KoenvE: pushing your file with some sort of filter and when pulling, you will be having a conflict for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git pushes *commits*, not files.  Commits contain files, but each commit contains a full snapshot of *all* files.  Commits also have a unique hash ID that is the *same* in *every* Git because it is computed from the complete contents *of* the commit.

Hence, if you want to have commit X locally in which file F appears "your way", commit X in *any* Git repository will have that copy of file F.  You will have to push to the other Git some different commit Y in which file F appears different.  Commits X and Y will be different commits and therefore be different history.  From this point forward, your repository and their repository are different repositories unless you let both repositories contain both histories.

It's OK to use the *same* branch name, in each repository, to refer to *different* commits and therefore different histories, because branch names are private to each repository; but it is literally impossible to use the same *commit*, in each repository, to contain different snapshots.  The drawback to having their `master` refer to commit `Y` (and later, commits derived from `Y`) while *your* `master` refers to commit `X` (and later, commits derived from `X`) is that you and/or other people will become confused by this situation.